# Reading char arrays from pipe giving garbage values

Tags: arrays, c, char, pipe

I'm trying to create a program that creates processes which then output specifically formatted characters into a pipe which the original process reads and outputs. The characters being written into the pipe are correctly formatted (I checked this by printing them with the commented out printf nested in the loops/created process), but when trying to read them I get garbage values. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char charsRead [100][6];
    char procB_chars[6] = "000aaa";
    char procC_chars[3] = "Xx0";
    int i, j, k, index, forkReturn, pipeReturn, numberRead;
    int fd[2];
    
    
    pipeReturn = pipe(fd);
    if(pipeReturn < 0{ printf("error creating pipe"); return;}

    forkReturn = fork();
    if(forkReturn == 0){
        close(fd[0]);
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                for(k = 0; k < 10; k++){
                    if(i == 0 && j == 0 && k == 0) k = 1;
                    procB_chars[0] = i + '0';
                    procB_chars[1] = j + '0';
                    procB_chars[2] = k + '0';
                    write(fd[1], procB_chars, 1);
                    //printf("%s \n", procB_chars);
                    index++;
                    if(index % 100 == 0)usleep(100);
                }
            }
        }   
        exit(0);
    }

    close(fd[1]);

    numberRead = 1;
    index = 0;
    i = 0;
    while(numberRead > 0){
        numberRead = read(fd[0], charsRead[index], 100);
        i = index;
        index += numberRead;
        for(i; i < index; i++) printf("%s \n", charsRead[i]);

    }
    
}
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: `%s` format is for null-terminated strings. `read()` doesn't add a null terminator.

Comment: You also may be writing outside the bounds of the `charsRead` array.

Comment: Why are you only writing 1 character from `procB_chars`, not all 3?

Comment: Wow, cannot believe I missed all these (well, I can, but embarassing lol). Thanks so much @Barmar!

Comment: Any idea how I would go about printing entries into my array if I can't guarantee the length? @Barmar

Comment: Since you're just writing 1 character at a time, why don't you read 1 character and print it? It's not clear what you're really trying to do here, why do you have a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time haha, it's an assignment with very oddly worded instructions that I have since found out are a lot less stringent than I thought. I ended up doing exactly what you said with the output and switching to a 1D array, thanks for your patience and advice! @Barmar